# How to make attachment downloadable - Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular

I have a scenario where user can upload files (PDF/PNG) and show if any files are already uploaded. I'm able to do Uploading part and showing the user any files are already uploaded. Now I want the user can download if any uploaded files are present on clicking on the attachment. Could you guys advise?

**ts** file

```
upload() {
    const fileUpload = this.fileUpload.nativeElement; //* retrieve native DOM element wrapped by ElementRef
    fileUpload.onchange = () => {
      const file = fileUpload.files[0]; // retrieve file
      if (file) {
        const filesize = getFileSizeHelper(file.size); // get file size
        if (filesize <= 2) {
          this.filename = file.name;
          this.uploadFile(file);
        } else {
          this.fileSizeEr.emit(true);
        }
      }
    };
    fileUpload.click(); // open file picker window
  }

  /**
   * method to upload file
   */
  uploadFile(file: any) {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', file, file.name);
    this.myservice.uploadFile(formData).subscribe((res: any) => {
      this.uploadedFile = res;
      this.fileUploadRes.emit(res); //emit response object to parent component
    });
  }
```

**HTML** file

```
<div class="upload-space" (click)="upload()">
  <mat-icon *ngIf="!doc?.fileName">publish</mat-icon>
  <span *ngIf="!doc?.fileName">
    {{ "PNG and PDF files allowed(max.2MB)" | translate }}
  </span>
  <span *ngIf="doc?.fileName">
    {{ doc.fileName }}
  </span>
  <!-- <span *ngIf="filename">
    {{ filename }}
  </span>-->
  <input
    type="file"
    #fileUpload
    id=""
    name="fileUpload"
    accept="image/*,application/pdf"
    style="display:none;"
  />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using blob, so after you created a link, with or without class="button", you should simply bind a function on (click) event with some identification property, and get it from your server, then, tell your httpget that the response type is blob.

With angular httpclient looks something like this:

```
//injected httpService from angular
this.httpClient.get('your controller', { responseType: blob}).subscribe( response => {
        const a = document.createElement('a'); // get the element
        const objectUrl = URL.createObjectURL(response); //create objecturl
        a.href = objectUrl; //make the <a></a> link's href to this object url
        a.download = 'any name you want to add'; 
        a.click(); //imitate a click on it
        //THE FOLLOWING STATEMENT IS ONLY FOR BE ABLE TO DOWNLOAD IT IN MS EDGE
        if (window.navigator && window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
          window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(response, 'any name you want to add' + ".pdf");
        }
        URL.revokeObjectURL(objectUrl);
})
```

I think its not the perfect solution, but it worked for me.